# Calculator with separate history window

Tags: windows, calculator

I am looking for a recommendation of a calculator which is capable of displaying the history, or the result of the calculation, in a separate window.

My goal is to be able to use two displays (monitor / tablet / etc.) and use the first to interact with the calculator, and use the second only to display the result or history.

Operating system needs to be Windows.